Blender 4.1.1 - cloth simulation remains distant from collision mesh
I'm using Blender 4.1.1 downloaded from the Blender site on Debian testing.
I'm trying to use the cloth simulation and it works as expected; but the cloth remains something as 5 centimeters distant from the character (I'm using 1 meter as the Blender unit).
I've set the collision distance to 0.001 meters and self-collision distance at 0.001 meters.
What I'm doing wrong?


Hello could you please share your file?

It is not necessary to write [SOLVED] in your question and answer. To show a question is solved you simply accept the answer (which is only available for answering yourself after a grace period).

I had to set the outer and inner thickness of the chearacter collision.
BTW if I try to set the thickness to 0 it is automaticalli adjusted to 0.001

